# AS3 Embedding assets - "Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data"

Tags: actionscript-3, image, video, preprocessor, embed

I've got an AS3 project where I'm trying to compile in  several images, a soundtrack, and a video via `[Embed]` metadata.  It's a product requirement that these be embedded, so network transfer is not an option.

I'm getting some really strange behavior - a sort of intermittent corruption of the compiled-in data.  Sometimes after the project compiles, I run the swf and it closes immediately and writes "Warning: Failed to parse corrupt data" to the flash log. If I delete the binary and clean the project, sometimes it'll run fine after building it again.  Sometimes it doesn't.

This is probably the strangest part about this problem, but sometimes when I see that error, I can physically move the video [Embed] lines to the end of the file, then clean the project, and it will build and run no problem.  Sometimes I move them back to the beginning of the file and it builds and runs fine.

It kinda seems like it might be a bug in the compiler. Has anyone else experienced something similar?  I'm targeting Flash 10.1 and using sprout (http://projectsprouts.org) to build my project.  This is the mxmlc line that's being used to compile (mxmlc Version 4.1.0 build 16076):

```
mxmlc -as3 -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries=true -debug -default-background-color=#ffffff -default-size 712 400 -output=bin/ProjectName.swf -source-path+=.preprocessed/src -source-path+=.preprocessed/assets .preprocessed/src/ProjectName.as
```

I've tried both removing the `-debug` compiler option and adding the `-optimize` option, but no luck.

Everything is being ran through the GNU C preprocessor for some other tasks, so maybe I'll try removing the preprocessor stuff and hardcoding those variables...I'll try that and post the results tomorrow.

Any insight at all would be much appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:**

This project is going to be compiled dynamically with different assets being embedded into the same codebase, so switching to something like Flash Builder for compilation really isn't an option...it must be done via command-line mxmlc.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out the corrupted data message was due to images created with Photoshop's "Save for web" feature.  If I save them outright as PNG images I don't get the message.  However, the intermittent nature of the movie compiling properly still seems to be an issue.  Now  sometimes when the project is compiled it won't throw any compiler errors, but I get a blank flash player window.  Right clicking in flash player shows a context menu with a message that says "Movie not loaded..."  This doesn't appear to have anything to do with things being ran through CPP first.

[[Screenshot]](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/7648771/flash_player_screenshot.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is apparently a bug in mxmlc under Mac OS X.  After posting this, I observed some other really strange behavior, so I switched the whole codebase to Windows 7.  Everything works as expected there (still using Project Sprouts as a build tool).

Answer (score 0):

Flash builder is fine with it.

Can you separate your issue for video or music only, or issue is true for both includes?

Comment: I haven't tried separating out the music and the video.  I'll give that a shot and see if the intermittence is remedied.

Comment: It looks like it has something to do with the music.  The project runs consistently with every asset but that one, and when I include just that it has issues.